# A question about infinitary proofs and First Order Peano Arithmetic

Tags: logic

In certain proof systems, infinite proofs are allowed; a common example is a version of Induction:

> Given $\Sigma \vdash \phi(S^n 0)$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$, infer $\Sigma \vdash \forall x \phi(x)$.

What is the relation with the system described in S.C.Kleene, Mathematical Logic [1967], pag.206 - Axiom Schema 3 (Induction):

> $A(0) \land \forall x(A(x) \rightarrow A(S(x))) \rightarrow A(x)$

In presence of (→ -E) may I "translate" the schema into a derived rule ?

If so, it does not look like an infinite rule.

Comment: If proofs with infinitely many steps are allowed, are there any undecidable problems left ?

Comment: @Peter: no; see http://m-phi.blogspot.com/2011/03/completeness-of-pa-with-omega-rule.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual axiom scheme of induction includes each axiom of the form
$$
(\phi(0) \land (\forall n)[\phi(n)\to\phi(n+1)]) \to (\forall n)\phi(n)
$$
If we were to write this as a derived inference rule, it would be
$$
\phi(0)\quad  (\forall n)[\phi(n)\to\phi(n+1)]\quad  \vdash (\forall n)\phi(n)
$$

This is not the same as the infinitary $\omega$-rule, which for each formula $\phi$ includes the following rule:
$$
\phi(0)\quad \phi(1)\quad  \phi(2)\quad  \cdots\quad  \vdash (\forall n)\phi(n)
$$

Note that for the derived rule from induction, there are exactly two hypotheses, while for the $\omega$-rule there are infinitely may hypotheses. A proof from the $\omega$-rule allows for completely separate subproofs of each $\phi(i)$, and so a proof that uses the $\omega$-rule will necessarily be infinite.

Comment: Thanks ! Are $\omega$-rule and Induction of equal "strenght" ?

Comment: No, the $\omega$-rule is much stronger.